# Authentication tests are failing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to implements security (HTTP Basic Auth + JWT) on a Spring Boot REST web service using `spring-mvc` and `spring-security`.

To achieve this, I'm using a SecurityContextRepository with two AuthenticationManagers.

Here is my SecurityContextRepository:

```java
@Component
public class MySecurityContextRepository implements SecurityContextRepository {

  private final JwtAuthenticationManager jwtAuthenticationManager;
  private final HttpBasicAuthAuthorizationManager httpBasicAuthAuthorizationManager;

  @Autowired
  public MySecurityContextRepository(JwtAuthenticationManager JwtAuthenticationManager,
      HttpBasicAuthAuthorizationManager httpBasicAuthAuthorizationManager) {
    this.jwtAuthenticationManager = jwtAuthenticationManager;
    this.httpBasicAuthAuthorizationManager = httpBasicAuthAuthorizationManager;
  }

  @Override
  public SecurityContext loadContext(HttpRequestResponseHolder requestResponseHolder) {
    HttpServletRequest request = requestResponseHolder.getRequest();

    String authHeader = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    if (authHeader == null) {
      return new SecurityContextImpl(null);
    }
    
    if (authHeader.startsWith("Bearer")) {
      String authToken = authHeader.substring(7);
      Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authToken, authToken);
      return new SecurityContextImpl(jwtAuthenticationManager.authenticate(auth));
    } else if (authHeader.startsWith("Basic")) {
      String authToken = authHeader.substring(6);
      Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authToken, authToken);
      return new SecurityContextImpl(httpBasicAuthAuthorizationManager.authenticate(auth));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void saveContext(SecurityContext context, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // Nothing to save here
  }

  @Override
  public boolean containsContext(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) != null
        && (request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION).startsWith("Bearer") ||
        request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION).startsWith("Basic"));
  }
}
```

And here is one of my AuthenticationManager

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {
  private final ObjectMapper mapper;
  private final JwtParser parser;

  public wtAuthenticationManager(ObjectMapper mapper, SecurityProperties security) {
    this.mapper = mapper;
    this.parser = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(security.getSigningKey());
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {

    String authToken = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    if (!validateToken(authToken)) {
      return null;
    }

    Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(authToken);
    String json = new JSONObject(claims).toString();
    try {
      HttpAuthUser user = mapper.readValue(json, HttpAuthUser.class);
      return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
    } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
      LOGGER.warn("Could not parse JWT", ex);
      return null;
    }
  }

  private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
    return parser.parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
  }

  private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
    try {
      final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
      return expiration.before(new Date());
    } catch (JwtException jwtException) {
      LOGGER.trace("Expired JWT", jwtException);
      return true;
    }
  }

  private Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
    return getAllClaimsFromToken(token).getExpiration();
  }

  private Boolean validateToken(String token) {
    return !isTokenExpired(token);
  }
}
```

And here is my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SecurityProperties.class)
public class Security extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  private final SecurityProperties securityProperties;
  private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;
  private final MySecurityContextRepository mySecurityContextRepository;

  @Autowired
  public Security(SecurityProperties securityProperties, SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport,
      MySecurityContextRepository mySecurityContextRepository) {
    this.securityProperties = securityProperties;
    this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
    this.mySecurityContextRepository = mySecurityContextRepository;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    /*
     * Roles authorisation is handled in the controllers.
     *
     * Domain object authorisations are handled by @Rbac* annotations
     */
    http.cors().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("regular", "admin")
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .securityContext().securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(
            (request, response, authException) -> {
              response.addHeader(AuthHelper.HEADER_WWW_AUTH, AuthHelper.HEADER_JWT_PREFIX);
              problemSupport.commence(request, response, authException);
            })
        .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport);
  }
}
```

When I launch my web service and try it with curl, everything works as expected: Authenticated requests works like a charms and un-authenticated one are rejected.

But my issue is when I run tests: all my requests are rejected.

Here is one of the failing test (same issue with Basic Auth authentication):

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AuthenticationTest {

  @Test
  @WithAnonymousUser
  public void testValidJwtToken() throws Exception {
 
    MvcResult response = this.mvc.perform(post("/api/auth/token")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content("{\"email\": \"test@test.com\", \"password\": \"super_password\"}"))
        .andExpect(status().isCreated())
        .andReturn();

    HttpAuth auth = mapper.readValue(response.getResponse().getContentAsString(),
        HttpAuth.class);

    String token = auth.getAccessToken();

    this.mvc.perform(get("/api/users").header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
}
```

It fails with `java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<401>`

In the debug output of the test, I can see a header "Authorization: Bearer foo.bar.foobar", and in the debug mode, that I go through my `JwtAuthenticationManager`.

Same thing occurs with `HttpBasicAuthAuthorizationManager`

Is there something I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: please read the spring documentation on how to properly implement JWT authentication. You have written a lot of unneeded custom security, and manual parsing of the JWT which already exists in spring security. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture i have no idea why you choose to use a security library, and then insist on implementing functionality that already exists. Whats the point of using a library then? also custom security is bad practice.

Comment: I don't use OAuth 2.0  and have the same issue with Http Basic Auth. Anyway, I read this article https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-security to try to understand Spring security

Comment: You are using oauth since you are reading the authorization header. You do know that the authorization header is part of oauth?

Comment: The article you posted talks about logging in using formLogin or basic login using username and password. You on the other hand is taking in a token using the authorization header which is part of the "resource server" documentation of oauth. You are basically building a custom login solution mixing formLogin with oauth2 resource server. Which is bad practice. Building custom security solutions are bad practice. Thats why there are security standards.

Comment: basic auth uses username and password, formlogin uses username and password. Tokens, are part of the oauth2 standard, and authenticating someone by using a token is part of the oauth2 resource server standard. And if you want to just login someone using a token, you should use what i posted instead of building a custom security solution.

Comment: I am using only JWT, and as I generate the JWT myself, I'm not using OAuth resource server at all. The JWT RFC does not talk about needing a OAuth resource server https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519 . And for the Http basic Auhentication, it's a legacy mechanism I have to maintain

Comment: I have not mentioned the JWT spec at all, it has nothing to do with this at all. What im talking about is that you have implemented the exact functionality of the oauth2 resource server functionality. Taking a JWT and authenticating someone. That is Exactly what oauth2 respurce server does. But you have written a custom solution when all this already exists in spring security. Writing custom security is bad practice, and what is the point of using a framework if you do not intend to use it. One bug in your custom security can compromise all the data. Are you willing to take that risk?

Comment: Read the documentation i posted, and you will se that all the code you have written to verify the JWT can be done in 3 for rows of code.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this when updating all our microservices to Spring Boot 2.6.0 right before the weekend. It was all fine beforehand.

It seems like they changed something in the `ErrorPageSecurityFilter` which should only be called when an `ERROR` gets dispatched. `MockMvc` does not seem to differ between all of this kind of dispatches and thus the filter blocks your request.

'Good news': For now you can disable it in your tests and `MockMvc` should work again. See: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28759#issuecomment-975398667 for a more detailed explanation and workaround.

Any chance your request works in a non-test environment?

Comment: Unfortunatly, I'm still using Srping Boot 2.5.3. But, indeed, my requests works as expected in a non test environment